# Rails deployment to production the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssh, automation

I have a Rails application that I develop on my local workstation and want to deploy this app to my Amazon AWS VPC in a best practice way. Currently, I give my web-server and database server a public IP and SSH into these boxes to configure. I am pretty sure this is nasty and want to explore better ways of doing this.

How should one correctly deploy code and database migrations to servers that sit within a private sub-net on AWS VPC? I have read that automation is key and people should disable SSH and port 22 all together, but I have no idea where to start configuring without logging in via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer.

Rails via elastic beanstalk is great, it can be automated with CI.

Ansible, puppet, any configuration manager would be an improvement.

The only thing that is safe to say: manual deployment is never the best practice. It's prone to error and create "user specific knowlege". Best practice would say to do anything that removes manual process, even if that's doing it via SSH from CI.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to take a look at ELB. What is "automate with CI"? Command line interface?